Two linear algebra theorems which I can't find anywhere...
I'm going through a linear algebra course where we have no textbook and the only reference is our prof's notes. Not a very fun experience, but on to the question: there are a definition and a theorem which I can't find anywhere, whether it be a textbook, other lecture notes, or even some random references on forums or papers.
Definition: Let $\sigma$ be a symmetric bilinear form on a vector space $V$. A basis $B$ is said to be regular if it can be transformed into an orthogonal basis through Lagrange's algorithm (the definition as it is stated in the slides only says "...through T1 transformations (which are the transformations used in Lagrange's algorithm)"
Let $n = \dim V$, and $p = rank(\sigma) \leq n$ (being the rank of any matrix which represents $\sigma$ in whichever basis we choose)
Theorem ("Jacobi's Theorem"): Under these hypotheses, a basis $B$ is regular iff the first $p$ principal minors have non zero determinant. (There is also a statement about how the matrix looks like after using Lagrange's algorithm, but it's not my main concern).
Can anyone help me find ANY resource on this definition + theorem? Also, I'm sure some of the other definitions I've used here are non-standard (and there may be a bit of difficulty with communication since I'm translating directly from Italian) so just let me know if I need to describe them better. Thanks!!
UPDATE: I found the textbook my professor took the definition from. It's "N. Melone - Introduzione ai metodi dell'algebra lineare". This probably will help very few people considering it's an obscure italian textbook, but there we go (maybe this will help my coursemates). Thanks for the help, still!

I suggest volume 1 of Gantmacher, Matrix Theory, translated into English about 1959;  I'll go look for more info, but I have both volumes (not sure how many volumes in the Russian original). Chapter 10, section 3, is called The Methods of Lagrange and Jacob of reducing a quadraticform to a sum of squares; there is a theorem of Jacobi.

I've just now taken a look at this book and yeah, that seems to be what I was looking for, although it's not a 1:1 match. The only thing I'm concerned is what my prof meant by "regular" basis but I guess I'll just ask him during office hours. Thank you!

suggest you look at my http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr .

I'll make sure to read it, thanks. By the way, is there any way I can mark this question as answered? I don't know if I would need an answer (which is not in the form of a comment) to do that, but I've forgotten to do it twice already and I'm not really happy about that.

I posted my first comment as an answer...   you mention slides, i might help if you gave a link for that, despite  the language. I may not get much out of one page of mathematics in Italian, but include the ten pages leading up to that and I can probably figure it out.

Actually, I should've been a bit more precise in my wording: they aren't slides, but my prof's handwritten notes, so they may be hard to read (they sure are for me!). Well, anyways, here they are. In "chronological" order, you may want to read bilinear forms then the two canonical form notes (the first one has some stuff about conics as well, you can probably skip that). If you have any trouble with translating some terms, or with the handwriting, just let me know. Thanks again, I really appreciate it.

From half of the first one, I suggest that he is  using Witt's  ideas. In English a good book is Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms. I'll need to see what he has in mind for canonical forms; Cassels does many things aimed at quadratic forms over the integers. ... Alright, page 24 of 36, he does distinguish between orthogonal and orthonormal  bases.

from earlier comment:
I suggest volume 1 of Gantmacher, Matrix Theory, translated into English about 1959; I'll go look for more info, but I have both volumes (not sure how many volumes in the Russian original). Chapter 10, section 3, is called The Methods of Lagrange and Jacob of reducing a quadratic form to a sum of squares; there is a theorem of Jacobi
